# Omitting a word when it referring to two actions

Tags: ellipsis, coordination

Here is my sentence.

> In our work, this is accomplished by ***identifying*** a **feature line** as a
>   step-edge and ***the orthogonal residuals*** of the edge points to the
>   fitted line.

My question is whether the term identifying is referring to both feature line and orthogonal residuals? Because I am not sure whether this tells my real idea and I want to say;

> .... by *identifying a feature line* as a step-edge *and identifying
>   (finding) the orthogonal residuals* of the edge ....

In this case, can I omit the **second identifying**?.

Comments are most welcome

Comment: Without the second *identifying*, I must think carefully what is (or are) the result(s) of identifying. This might be a burden for your readers, especially if they don't know about your project before and just jump right into the page. So, why punish the readers?

Comment: You might omit the second *identifying*; but as the sentence stands you should not use that verb. The English expression  *identify A to B* means *tell B who A is*, as in *He identified the President to me*.

Comment: @StoneyB: that mean, I should use another word for second case like finding. Is that you are telling or remove identifying from the whole sentence and use a word e.g. finding once only?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "identifying (or finding) the residuals ... **to** the fitted line." There are too many technical details here for me to advise you what you should do.

Comment: @StoneyB: actually, I work with point data. so, after identifying an edge, we are computing orthogonal distance between each point to the line  passing through the edge points (say fitted line).

Comment: @gnp Ah! Let me see if I have this right. You identify the feature line; then you measure the (shortest) distances between each of the remaining (i.e. residual) points (which are ?whatever points the feature line does not actually pass through?) and the fitted line--which is the feature line you have just identified? And that distance of course is measured along a line orthogonal to the fitted/feature line?

Comment: This requires a picture for us to understand the technical relationships.

Answer (score 4):

What seems natural to me is "In our work, this is accomplished by identifying both a feature line as a step-edge and the orthogonal residuals of the edge points to the fitted line." The "both" makes it clear that the reader or listener should expect two objects to relate to "identifying".